# Replace forward slash "/ " character in JavaScript string?

Tags: javascript

I have this string:

```
var someString = "23/03/2012";
```

and want to replace all the "/" with "-".

I tried to do this:

```
someString.replace(///g, "-");
```

But it seems you cant have a forward slash `/` in there.

Comment: helpful for pass the parameters to the query string so like decoding then encode them in destination page querystring

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You need to escape your slash.

```
/\//g
```

Answer (score 40):

Try escaping the slash: `someString.replace(/\//g, "-");`

By the way - `/` is a (forward-)slash; `\` is a backslash.

Answer (score 21):

First of all, that's a forward slash. And no, you can't have any in regexes unless you escape them. To escape them, put a *backslash* (`\`) in front of it.

```
someString.replace(/\//g, "-");
```

[**Live example**](http://jsfiddle.net/wC8Cc/)

Answer (score 5):

Just use the **split - join** approach:

```
my_string.split('/').join('replace_with_this')
```

Answer (score 4):

Escape it: `someString.replace(/\//g, "-");`

Answer (score 4):

Remove all forward slash occurrences with blank char in `Javascript`.

```
modelData = modelData.replace(/\//g, '');
```

Answer (score 3):

You can just replace like this,

```
 var someString = "23/03/2012";
 someString.replace(/\//g, "-");
```

It works for me..

Answer (score 2):

The option that is not listed in the answers is using `replaceAll`:

```
 var someString = "23/03/2012";
 var newString = someString.replaceAll("/", "-");
```

Answer (score -1):

`Area.replace(new RegExp(/\//g), '-')` replaces multiple forward slashes (`/`) with `-`